# How to insert Pandas dataframe that's 1 row but multiple columns into a single SQL cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I originally had a JSON object which I have looped through and filtered and then converted to a Python [ ] list and have now put it into a Panda's dataframe.

The PD dataframe stands at 1 row x 79 columns, as I wanted, each column has the single word in it I was looking to get.

I want each of these single words in their respective DF columns to be listed in a delimited format so they fit into a single SQL cell. (I suppose their could be semi-colons between them instead)

So something like:

```
df_words.to_sql('relevant_database', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

How do I fit an entire list of words so they go to SQL and land in a single cell under a specific column?

eg original DF:

```
       column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 etc... etc...
Row 1  Object    Object   Object   Object   Object
```

eg expected result in Postgres:

```
 Column_1  Column_2     relevant_word_column   Column_4 ... etc. etc.
                         
                        *(single cell below
                         fits all Dataframe
                         columns as words)*

Row 1                    Object; object; obj..
Row 2
Row 3
```

Comment: try to break this problem down in two steps: first create a column with the right values, then write only that columns to sql.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer.  As per the comment, breaking down the problem to the first part and to get the cells joined...

**Given:**

```
    column_1    column_2    column_3    column_4    column_5
0   This        And         That        And         Another
```

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

delimChar = '; '

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': {0: 'This'},
 'column_2': {0: 'And'},
 'column_3': {0: 'That'},
 'column_4': {0: 'And'},
 'column_5': {0: 'Another'}})

df = df.astype(str) + delimChar
df['wholeRow'] = df.sum(axis=1).astype(str)
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    column_1    column_2    column_3    column_4    column_5    wholeRow
0   This;       And;        That;       And;        Another;    This; And; That; And; Another;
```

**Additional:**

```
# get the cell as a string
myCell = df.loc[0,'wholeRow']
```

**Outputs (space at the end):**

```
This; And; That; And; Another;
```